# WBS and Project management

Tags: work-breakdown-structure, small-projects, schedule, deliverables, work-in-progress

I have 2 doubts about the WBS and project management and the ongoing progress of the project.

WBS is decomposition of a project into deliverables.
The lowest level or unit of work within a deliverable is a work package.
In a work package we can define the activities involved to produce that deliverable.

If we talk about a project like CAR, the WBS would be like (only work packages):

```
CAR
+ Engine
  + Cylinder
  + Piston
     + Head
     + Body
     + Oil ring
  + Shaft
+ Body
```

Then we can work on the activities of the HEAD work package as follows

```
- design head
- get a prototype
- manufacture head
- test head
- etc.
```

**First doubt**

On a IT project context or even the car, is it correct to include project management as a deliverable that include multiple management processes like this? (I am combining the WBS with the activities in the work package)

```
MY PROJECT
+ Project Management (Supposed to do this in a fast tracking)
  + Scope management (work package)
    + Create scope statement 
    + Create WBS 
    + Create WBS dictionnary
    + Scope baseline (MILESTONE)
  + Resources management (work package)
    + Get resources calendar
    + Assign resources to project
    + Resources matrix (MILESTONE)
+ Deployment (Deliverable)
  + Database (Work package)
    + Create database 
    + Execute scripts
    + Created database (MILESTONE)
  + Website (Work package)
...
...
```

**Second doubt**

Where can I place the ongoing progress activities of the project. Let's say that you already defined all the planned activities in a work package, but it is suppossed that you can add activities from coordinations with your client as soon as don't change your scope. It should be great to schedule these activities from coordinations to track time, progress and cost within the budget.

Will you include a deliverable Analysis or Execution as deliverable and decompose it until a work package where I could include ongoing activities with the client? Do you have a link to share of a WBS of a real IT project as model?

Analysis and Execution would look like phases of my project, that's why I getting confused about how to structure my schedule that harmonizes my WBS.